# virt-manager copy paste to vm in text mode

Tags: virtual-machine

How can I copy paste in text mode from host to guest virtual machine?  I have read answers that recommend using spice, but that works for X sessions, not in text mode, or not from host's X session to guest text mode.

I don't need graphics mode in the guest since it is to test a server.

I am using qemu-system and libvirt.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can't. However, when you define a [serial console](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#console) in the VM, you can access it in a normal terminal with `virsh console` and use copy-paste. In addition to specifying a serial console in the XML file (or via virt-manager, if that is possible), you will also have to set a kernel parameter like `console=ttyS0`.

Comment: Thank you berndbaush.  Actually the solution is very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the solution is simple, just connect to the VMs using your normal terminal by ssh in which you can use cut & paste.

Comment: Great method, but I had to look up what host to put in the ssh command. One way is to run `ip addr` in the VM and use the numbers in the `inet` line. So, `ssh root@192.168.123.45` for example